# Highstock yAxis missing reserveSpace option

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highstock to do some chart rendering.

I need to use the 'reserveSpace' option for yAxis labels (I need to set the option to true).

The problem is: reserveSpace option is present in the Highcharts API (see link https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.reserveSpace), but is missing in the Highstock API (see link https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels)

From Highchart site, the difference between Highcharts and Highstock is "Highstock is based on Highcharts, meaning it has all the core functionality of Highcharts, plus some additional features." (see https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock)

So why the reserveSpace option is missing in Highstock? 
Do you know if there is a way to integrate in Highstock the same reserveSpace behaviour already present in Highcharts?

Thank you

Comment: Editing the margin could be a workaround, see: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.marginLeft

Comment: It seems that it works here http://jsfiddle.net/Lukydxhe/. Do you have an example with your chart?

Comment: @ewolden : unfortunately, that workaround cannot be applied in my case. This is because numeric data can be very different: sometimes I receive values such 10.12, other times I receive values such 300000000.1234. Applying a static margin can resolve the problem, but when the numeric value is short, like in 10.12, there is too much wasted space.

Comment: @morganfree In you fiddle is working because the yAxis is on the left and yAxis labels are aligned to the right. In the documentation of Highcharts is written (see my first link in first post): reserveSpace 'Whether to reserve space for the labels. By default, space is reserved for the labels in these cases:

- On all horizontal axes.
- On vertical axes if label.align is right on a left-side axis or left on a right-side axis.
- On vertical axes if label.align is center.'

Comment: @morganfree I edited ur fiddle, putting yAxis on the right with labels on the right and it works! Eventually, there is another option in my test that cause some conflicts with reserveSpace. Thank you ;)